# tagsets for events

Tags: civievent, tags

Can tagsets be used for events?

We want to track the issues that folks care about - whether that's expressed by attending a particular event, signing a petition (drupal webform) or mentioning it in a phone call.

I can see that tagsets can be used for attachments, contacts, activities and cases - but what about events?!

The civi book shows a nice example of using tagsets for precisely our use case under tagsets here: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/

If tagsets can't be used for events, I presume we'll need a custom field, which is ok but obviously not a flexible for users.

Comment: Is it that you want the tagset to show up on the event registration page?

Comment: no, sorry the question was unclear, we want the tagset to show up on the new event admin page, so that events (and hence participations) can be classified by issue.